# WPF Buttons not instantiating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, mvvm

I'm having the weirdest problem and it's driving me insane.

I've created a WPF MVVM program and everything was working alright, however, now when I open the program and click on a button, I receive a System.NullReferenceException. I put a breakpoint where the error occurs and the button isn't instantiated, however, the form shows just fine and the buttons are clickable. In fact, none of the buttons instantiate (every button on my form gives the same error, and when I set a breakpoint after InitializeComponent(), none of the buttons show up under this - all the other components show up.

Here is sample code for the button:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Button Content="A" 
        Command="{Binding KeyButtonClickCommand}"
        Style="{StaticResource keyButtonStyle}" />
```

The method throwing an error is in my ViewModel, the button is bound to a command:

```
private void keyButton_Click(object sender)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;
  string tempKey = "";
  tempKey = btn.Content.ToString();
  this.Key = tempKey;            
}
```

Breakpoint after InitializeComponent()

[image: Breakpoint after InitializeComponent]

Breakpoint after error

[image: Breakpoint at error location]

Like I said, was working just fine earlier, now just went on the fritz.

What worries me most is that maybe I've done something that I shouldn't have and it might affect future projects. I'd just like to double-check whether it's that, or just a freak occurrence.

Thanks.

Comment: restart visual studio. If it is caused by your code, did you use version control to enable you to backtrace ?

Comment: Are you saying that sender is null and that is your problem?

Comment: So is 'btn' the object that's null or the 'btn.Content'?  You may want to look at the sender object and send that to us

Comment: Yes, the sender is null, Slowbrochacho

Comment: Sending a Button into the ViewModel.  Well, that isn't MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly you are getting the argument for your keyButton_Click method as null.

This is most likely because you are not passing in a CommandParameter to your command. If you want to pass the button itself into the command, try the following XAML.

```
<Button Content="A" 
        Command="{Binding KeyButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Style="{StaticResource keyButtonStyle}" />
```

I do want to note the whole point of MVVM is to not interact with the actual UI layer directly in your ViewModel and when you pass your button to your ViewModel like this you are doing exactly that.

**Edit :** As noted in the comments if you want to pass "A" as argument to your command you should just set that as your CommandParameter.

```
<Button Content="A" 
            Command="{Binding KeyButtonClickCommand}"
            CommandParameter="A"
            Style="{StaticResource keyButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: Agree , in this case passing 'A' as the command parameter makes most sense.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried using the CommandParameter, sounds like a much better idea. I just added the CommandParameter, didn't change anything else to see if the button really didn't instantiate, here's the error I got after. http://imgur.com/dORLRQu

Comment: @Sethmo011 It looks like it worked perfectly, your command parameter which is your methods argument in that image looks like it is the string "A" which is not a button hence why btn = null. Because you are trying to cast a string to the type button.

Comment: Ok, seemed to have done the trick, thanks for the idea, everything seems to be firing off just fine, except my UI isn't updating, not sure why yet. It's nearly midnight here and I'm running on empty, I'll sort it out tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Everything works, sorted out the UI issue. From now on I know to use CommandParameter. First MVVM app done. 

http://i.imgur.com/yCMn60A.png